# Convert "deepToString()" back to 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to use this method to convert a 2D Array to string into a properties file. Then, import it from the properties by converting the properties string back to a 2D Array. But I have difficulties with converting the String back to a 2D array.

EDIT: I want to reverse the 2D array string output back to 2D array. But the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456367/reverse-parse-the-output-of-arrays-tostringint) you gave me doesn't help me with the 2D array one. As the Arrays.replace() can't replace the 2D array's internal one.

Here's my code:

```
public static void getSettings(){
try {
File file = new File("config.properties");
Properties p = new Properties();
FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
//Import
moduleNames = p.getProperty("moduleNames").split("");
moduleData = ??? //I don't know how to convert String to String[][]
}
catch (Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Here's the another function to set property:

```
public static void writeFile(String[][] mD, String[] mN){
try{
Properties p = new Properties;
File file = new File("config.properties");

p.setProperty("moduleData", Arrays.deepToString("mD"));
p.setProperty("moduleNames", Arrays.toString("mN"));
//...further more code to flush the data out
} catch (Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Can anyone tell me how to convert String (from deepToString) back to String[][]?

My project is in Open source. This: [Conf.java Line271](https://github.com/mob41/ComGardening/blob/master/ComGardening/com/mob41/comgarden/Conf.java#L271) is the set properties one.

And this: [Conf.java Line215](https://github.com/mob41/ComGardening/blob/master/ComGardening/com/mob41/comgarden/Conf.java#L215) is the load String to String[][] one.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456367/reverse-parse-the-output-of-arrays-tostringint

Comment: @Tom You can vote for duplicate.

Comment: There is no method in the java API that will automatically convert this back to an array that i know of. someone already did the thing you need : [stringToDeep](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22428926/4088809) @YoungHobbit :)

Comment: No, I am asking for multidimensional array.
But thank you Tom and Tahar Bakir for the URL, it also helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any standard method that could do that. But using the ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/456393/1216775) I have formulated the following:

```
        String[][] sample = new String[][]{{"Apple", "Ball"},{"Cat", "Dog"}, {"Elephant, Fish"} };
        String temp = Arrays.deepToString(sample);
        String[] strings = temp.replace("[", "").replace("]", ">").split(", ");
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String[]> tempResult = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String str : strings) {
            if(str.endsWith(">")) {
               str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
               if(str.endsWith(">")) {
                   str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
               }
               stringList.add(str);
               tempResult.add(stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()]));
                stringList = new ArrayList<>();
            } else {
                stringList.add(str);
            }
        }
       String[][] originalArray = tempResult.toArray(new String[tempResult.size()][]);
```

This has lots of scope for improvement and I hope you will do that. This is just for hint purpose for converting the String back to a 2D array.

Comment: Thank you! Your code helps me. But Tahar Bakir's comment has solved my problem.